# How to give right -click save as pdf option in react table cell

Tags: reactjs, pdf, blob, react-table, save-as

Have a react table cell, which is clickable, on clicking, a pdf is downloaded. 
How can i give a right click save as pdf option ?
The cell used to be an href, so, right click option was available by default.

href was changed to a function call onclick. Now when i right click, i get only save as html format . Any thought s?

```
<a                                                              
onClick={this.handleClick(<parameter>)}>                                                                                                                        
</a>

handleClick = param => e => {
event.preventDefault();
fetch(param).then(function(response) {
    if(response.ok) {
        return response.blob();
    }
}).then(function(response) {
    if (response != undefined){
         const file = new Blob([response])
         saveAs(file, 'fileName');
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
});

}
```

Downloads works fine when clicking the cell, but i don't have a save as pdf option when i right click ?

Thoughts ?

P.S: it used to be available by default when the download link was just an href

`<a  href={link}>
</a>`

Comment: Maybe give this a try? https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

I have not used it myself, but it seems to do what you need.